# Azure VM reserved IP from Dashboard vs. Preview Portal?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I can create a VM using the Preview Portal and assign a reserved IP address with no problem and I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same via the Azure dashboard?

I know you can use Powershell - but I'm absolutely the worst powershell person - I can never get it to do what I want :) And, I'm not completely alien to command line - I run a bunch of linux boxes…just useless with Powershell.

What I've been doing is creating the VM in the Preview Portal so I can assign the reserved IP but the Preview Portal doesn't always work properly (it's still being developed I think?) in that it doesn't always see all my images that are available from the dashboard and, even the images it sees I sometimes get generic failures when trying to create a VM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cross-platform Azure CLI to create and use [reserved IP addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2014/10/03/azure-xplat-cli-tool-0-8-10-released-with-reserved-ip-features.aspx). In fact, you can use the CLI to [manage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) most aspects of Azure compute.

Comment: Thanks Neil - I didn't know about that one! I'm guessing that it can't be done from the Azure dashboard, then? The commands within Powershell - and looking at CLI it seems similar - is that they are, seemingly, very long ;) But I am going to give CLI a shot and mark this as a good answer since it's definitely easier than Powershell - thank you again!

Comment: Most new features aren't being added to the Azure Dashboard (Production Portal) as attention is being directed to the Preview Portal.

Comment: I see how to create them in the cross clis, but not how to assign them. It will only assign the instance ip.